# Data set join using EMR

Tags: join, hadoop, amazon-web-services, emr

I have 2 tab-delimited datasets stored in AWS S3.
I am trying to write an EMR job that will join these 2 datasets based on a common key (a set of field values).
My current version populates 2 lists and compares them line by line; outputting the rows that have a common key.
I have been writing in python but cannot seem to figure out the logic behind bringing 2 files through stdin and comparing each row with one another in order to join the two datasets.
Most of the documentation I find is in Java.
I am using Amazon's EMR to run all my jobs.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

thank you

Comment: Do you need to write the code in python?

Comment: preferably yes. I'm currently looking at pig as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using EMR already, have you looked at Hive?

http://aws.amazon.com/articles/Elastic-MapReduce/3681655242374956

Comment: I appreciate the input. I've actually solved this problem by using PIG and performing a JOIN. It was as simple as that!